# Lambda com List

Tags: c#

Tenho as classes:

```
public class Modulo
{
    [Key]
    public int ModuloID { get; set; }
    public int SatisfacaoID { get; set; }

    public virtual Satisfacao Satisfacao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AlunoSatisfacao> AlunoSatisfacoes { get; set; }
}

public class AlunoSatisfacao
{
    public int AlunoSatisfacaoID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int SatisfacaoID { get; set; }
    public int AlunoID { get; set; }
    public int ModuloID { get; set; }

    public virtual Satisfacao Satisfacao { get; set; }
    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }
    public virtual Modulo Modulo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AlunoSatisfacaoResposta> AlunoSatisfacaoRespostas { get; set; }
}

public class AlunoSatisfacaoResposta
{
     [Key]
     public int AlunoSatisfacaoRespostaID { get; set; }
     public int AlunoSatisfacaoID { get; set; }
     public int SatisfacaoPerguntaID { get; set; }
     public string Resposta { get; set; }

     public virtual AlunoSatisfacao AlunoSatisfacao { get; set; }
     public virtual SatisfacaoPergunta SatisfacaoPergunta { get; set; }
}
```

Dado um `Modulo`, quero saber quantos `AlunoSatisfacaoResposta` tem a `resposta` 2 e `SatisfacaoPerguntaID` 2.

Algo tipo (Sei que isso não é possível):

```
var modulo = PegarModulo(5);
int countResposta = modulo.AlunoSatisfacao.Where(x=> x.AlunoSatisfacaoRespostas.Resposta = 2 && x.AlunoSatisfacaoRespostas.SatisfacaoPerguntaID = 2).Count();
```

Comment: Você quer saber quem digitou no campo de resposta o número 2 e o Id da pergunta é 2, é isso mesmo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int countResposta = modulo.AlunoSatisfacoes.Where(
                        x => x.AlunoSatisfacaoRespostas.Any(
                            y => y.Resposta == "2" && y.SatisfacaoPerguntaID == 2
                        )
                    ).Count();
```